# Samba: smbd unrecognized service

Tags: debian, samba, daemon

Running `service smbd restart` on a Debian Home server gives me an error reading ***smbd unrecognized service***. The service ran fine after the initial installation, with the abbreviated output being:

```
apt-get install samba samba-common samba-client
(...)
starting service smbd nsmbd
```

At the moment the only way I can get it to restart is by reinstalling it (apt-get install --reinstall samba)!

How do I properly restart this service?

Answer (score 3):

The service name is wrong. Try "samba" as [suggested here](http://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2001-February/024404.html).

i.e

```
service samba restart 
# or
service smb restart
```